# filter postgresql query result

Tags: sql, postgresql, filter

I have multiple tables that need to be merged into one.

```
SELECT name, SUM(money) AS MONEY FROM transactions
JOIN results ON transactions.id = results.id
JOIN more ON results.per_id = more.per_id
GROUP BY name
```

The output is person's name (first column) and person's money (second column).

```
name | money
aaron  1220
mike   800
john   200
kate   600
```

Now I try to filter the result by a money amount, i.e. to show results for people with "Sum(money) > 500"

for that reason I tried putting "WHERE money > 500 GROUP BY name" however the output was wrong (aaron 1000, mike 610, etc..).

how do you write a query to filter the **last/ending** result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Group By Name
having sum(money) > 500
```

EDIT : what do you meen by "last / ending result" ?

Comment: I've tried to add "GROUP BY name HAVING money > 500" but got an error.. the problem was that I never used SUM ().. to think that the solution was so close. Thank you Raphaël

Answer (score 4):

If you want to have the `SUM(money)` that is greater then 500. Then you can do like this:

```
SELECT name, SUM(money) AS MONEY FROM transactions
JOIN results ON transactions.id = results.id
JOIN more ON results.per_id = more.per_id
GROUP BY name
HAVING SUM(money)>500
```